# Provide a mechanism for users to comment on a job listing

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

Recently, I answered a job listing on Careers 2.0 and interviewed with the company.  I progressed to the developer test stage where I decided the way the company did its "developer test" did not agree with me.  To save others a potentially time consuming and unrewarding experience, I would like the ability to comment on the job listing.

I would imagine this feature would be best implemented with a rep minimum, and maybe a rep hit.

Comment: Consider leaving an interview review on [Glassdoor](http://www.glassdoor.com/) instead.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about [so], but about [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) instead. Feature requests for Careers 2.0 should be made on [meta.se].

Comment: Why is there a [careers] tag?  Shouldn't careers tagged questions be migrated then?  Also, I figured it went here as the site is a stackoverflow subdomain.  Should I wait for an admin to migrate it or delete it and post it to meta stackexchange?  As far as posting to Glassdoor, I did that, but having not known about Glassdoor until after it happened to me, how many other developers might not know about that site?

Comment: Maybe your question is fine here on Meta, I don't know. Wait for other people to respond. As for the job review thing, I don't predict that as being a big hit with the Stack Exchange team, because they make part of their revenue from selling job postings to employers. I don't think employers will be as excited to post their jobs here if they knew that dissatisfied candidates could give them negative reviews.

Comment: I thought about that, and there is not a good way around it (while keeping the commenting feature on the Stack Exchange side).  There was a post on Meta.stackexchange that I just looked at that spoke of feedback to the company that is not visible to the other users.  While it is good to tell a company what they are doing wrong, there is no guarantee that they will follow through, and they may very well end up roping some other poor soul in just like they have been.

Comment: If you think that this particular company is doing something shady or unethical, you could consider reporting them to the Stack Exchange team. I'm not sure how Stack Exchange would respond to that though.

Comment: I think I will.  I don't know how they would view it, but I certainly wouldn't do it as a business owner.  See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/244593/is-my-work-on-a-developer-test-being-taken-advantage-of/

Comment: Careers questions should be posted/migrated to Meta SE.

Comment: Makes total sense, though it can be too easily abused e.g. frustrated person who was rejected telling things that are not true out of frustration. So maybe require approval of some sort of the comments.

Answer (score 2):

That's probably not something that's going to happen.

First, there's no way to guarantee that people who don't get the job or not offered an interview won't use it as retribution.

Second, we already have a flagging system for users in case a company is doing something truly scummy.

Third, it's a simple issue of manpower. Because Careers is a paid product, it would really have to be moderated by paid employees. Right now we don't have the manpower to moderate or even implement the system you're requesting.

Comment: I can get behind that, and I certainly agree that unless it was heavily moderated, it could quickly devolve into retribution commenting.  "These guys suck.  I didn't get the job because they saw that I was X".